# Do a stored procedure not infer permission on internal operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

SQL Server ....

I have long been under the assumption that granting stored procedure exec to a principal means that the SP can do whatever it needs to do and optionallly return a result.

I am developing currently on a 2012 database. I created a SP and granted exec to a SQL login. 
The user got error messages. 
I also had to grant rights on a table and a function that I use inside the SP.

My world view also held that views and functions did NOT transfer rights in this way.

Has something changed? Have I just operated under a false pretense all this time?

I have googled for an answer, but cant seem to find an article that discusses this topic.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Greg

Comment: Are any of the tables on a different database to the stored procedure? By default cross database [ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) is disabled in SQL Server.

Comment: same database. but different schemas.  Ownership chaining is the term i needed to search.  Thanks for that.  The different schemas are the reason this wasnt behaving as I expected.

Comment: No problem. I suspect everything you will ever need to know, and probably more can be found [in this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 0):

Databaes chaining is the concept that addresses these type issues. 
In 2005 forward, the notion of owner of an object became the notion of the schema that holds the object.

In my particular case, the stored procudure is in one schema , the function in another, and the table in yet another schema. Hence the need for these multiple grants.

I have never really used schemas before this assignment. Thats just how they do things here, and thats ok. Hence, my surprise at this behaviour.

Greg